# How to pass link directly for my fb fan page using fb api

Tags: php, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I have used link attribute under api() array and tried giving that link directly but somehow it is ot working showing 404 page not found error. Can we display iframe directly for fb fan page. Imean whichever iframe code we will send that should get displayed on fb page
below is the code i am using writing on fb page

```
$facebook->api(
    "/".$this->data['pageid']."/tabs/app_".$this->data['selectmyid'],
    "post",
    array(
        "access_token" => $pageAccessToken,
        "custom_image_url" => "http://socialmobiapps.com/members/publishing-option/images/pagetab.png",
        "link" => "http://linkconnect.me/published_deals/134/",
        "custom_name" => $name1
    )
);
```

Comment: no one likes unreadable 300 character long one liners