# Invalid parameters while posting to facebook page

Tags: codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am using below code to post contents to Facebook page that user admins.

I can get the post successful if I just pass 'message' => 'Check out my new blog post!' parameter. But when I try to add link or picture, it returns nothing. Sometimes invalid parameters.

But the documentation shows you can pass link. Can anyone tell what is wrong here.

I am using Facebook sdkphp 4.0 version

```
$page_post = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'POST', '/'. $fb_account_id .'/feed', array('link' => 'http://www.example.com/','message' => 'Check out my new blog post!', ) ))>execute()>getGraphObject()->asArray();
// return post_id
print_r( $page_post );
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30860703/how-to-pass-link-directly-for-my-fb-fan-page-using-fb-api/30860845#30860845

Comment: I am sorry, I couldn't find the answer or might be missing something here. I created codeigniter library, and when I just use message parameter, it gets post successfully, but the issue occurs only when I use link, picture parameter.

Comment: http://benmarshall.me/facebook-sdk-php-v4-codeigniter/ read this article as well

Comment: Abdulla, I could see the link that you have me contains the code to get the access token. I am using the same approach here. I created library and have long lived access token. Its being saved to database. I can post message, picture to user timeline, but this issue is only for posting to facebook page with picture or link parameter.

Comment: Have you checked the Facebook graph API page ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this one

`$page_post = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'POST', '/me/feed', array('link' => 'http://www.example.com/','message' => 'Check out my new blog post!', ) ))->execute(); $response = $page_post->getGraphObject(); 
// return post_id 
print_r( $response );`